# How to get Date & Time from Database table column in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

I'm trying to store and get current date & time from Database. I'm trying this

```
  $current_time    = Carbon::now(); 
  'order_date_and_time'    => $current_time,
  'delevery_date_and_time' => $current_time->addDays(3),
```

Here is my migration

```
   $table->dateTime('order_date_and_time');
   $table->dateTime('delevery_date_and_time');
```

I store current date & time perfectly but I couldn't get date & time. I use this method to get DateTime

```
      toDateTimeString()
```

I got this error

```
 "Call to a member function toDateTimeString() on string"
```

Can anyone tell me how can I get Date & Time ?

Comment: Can you show how you're getting the data, and attempting to use it?

Comment: I'm trying to display date and time in view blade like this way                                         {{$data->order_date_and_time ->toDateTimeString()}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `order_date_and_time` and `delevery_date_and_time` to `$dates` in your model. It will cast the attributes to Carbon instance as said in [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

```
protected $dates=[
    'order_date_and_time',
    'delevery_date_and_time',
];
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But how to set local time zone?  I got this by Carbon::now()  Thu, Feb 11, 2021 8:42 PM

Comment: @Prince check your app.php in the config folder. It has a setting for the timezone.

Comment: I changed that but didn't work, Then I add Time_Zone in .env and also add this 'timezone'        => env('TIME_ZONE', 'UTC'), in config.  It worked.